# Juniper Network Connect crashing on Ubuntu 14.04 32-bit

Tags: 14.04, networking

Previously, I had Ubuntu 64-bit installed, but having tried all solutions for running JNC on 64-bit, I decided to downgrade to 32--bit.

But apparently, the problem remains the same. JNC crashes before any IP is assigned. I have only Oracle Java 7 installed. The output of `java -version` is:

```
java version "1.7.0_80"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_80-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 24.80-b11, mixed mode)
```

Output of `update-alternatives --config java` is:

```
 Selection    Path                                     Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
*  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java   1         auto mode
```

Firefox also has the plugin installed and enabled. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution to the issue. Your home folder contains the `.juniper_networks` and so if it is encrypted, then JNC has problems. So make sure your home folder is not encrypted.